# Multiline headline w/ background color in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

So i want a multiline headline with a background color and a gap in between lines. I got it working using some css hacks in Chrome/Safari/IE9+ but Firefox refuses to display it correctly. At the beginning of the new line, the span element should have a left border. FF does display the border, but the background-color is missing.

I know, `<br>` inside `h1/span` is kind of ugly, but I need the line breaks to be adjustable and multiple `h1` tags are worse imho.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLL7100q/

Thanks!

Comment: This fiddle works for me in Chrome and FF. I changed the color from transparent to red to make sure the border was definitely there. Not sure what you mean: https://jsfiddle.net/hLL7100q/2/

Comment: do you have an image of what you are trying to accomplish?  I'm not sure I understand the exact look you are going for?

Comment: @MiaMarks I think OP wants the same result in Firefox than in Chrome

Comment: OP Is there a solution in this article? https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

Comment: that's where i got the basics from, but i needed controllable padding left and right. there is no real solution in article sadly..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For modern browsers there is a property called "box-decoration-break". So your code should look like this:

**CSS**

```
box-decoration-break: clone;
```

[Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxdecorationbreak) for inline-elements is ok but not overwhelming.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLL7100q/56/

Comment: Thanks for providing the correct answer. I totally forgot about this question, but this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

change like this .

```
h1 span {
  box-shadow: 17px 0 0 #000, 0px 0 0 #000;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

I think it will helps you .

Comment: this removes the padding on the right (at least in chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Negative box-shadow value leads to this issue. You can simply avoid this issue changing this property -

```
box-shadow: 17px 0 0 #000, 0px 0 0 #000;
```

Comment: @Vijay - Nice idea. I think if you are using separate span for each line, you can simply ignore br tags with css padding/margin or any other property

Comment: this removes the padding on the left side which is not what i need. i need there to be 17px padding with a background color on each line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<h1>
    <span>supertest<br></span>
      <span>  headline with<br></span>
      <span>  a lot of words</span>
</h1>
```

it woks i guess

---

if u really think above code dint work for you try this with out br tags.

html

```
<h1>
 <div>
    <span>
        supertest
        headline with
        a lot of words
        </span>
 </div>
</h1>
```

css

```
h1 span {
    box-shadow: 17px 0 0 #000;
    background-color: #000;
}
div{
    width:200px;
}
```